# how to get motherboard serial number when /sys/class/dmi is not available on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, serial-number, system-information

I need to bind the software key with the motherboard.

Everything seems ok on systems like Slackware, Debian and Arch which run as virtual machines in VirtualBox. (`/sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid`)

Now we have industry pcs, which have Arch linux and when i try to find the information about motherboard it seems to be absent. There is no folder /sys/class/dmi. I then installed `dmidecode` and it failed to retrieve information with error `No SMBIOS nor DMI entry point found, sorry.`

Is there another way of getting the information i need?

If you know another, alternate or better, way of binding SW to HW then please do tell, but our goal is to let clients upgrade RAM, HDD, NIC or VGA without having us generate software serial for the new PC layout.

EDIT1: The software is created using c++, at this point i was only thinking of how to get the information using the bash script, as i can easily run the commands from my c++ program and get the output needed, but maybe there is another way using some c++ functions?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/ids.html It suggests the best ID for uniquely identifying a system instance is to use `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id`. However this does have the drawback of requiring dbus, not being tied to any particular hardware, and (presumably) not surviving a system reinstall.

Comment: dbus/machine-id seems to be present, however "not surviving a system reinstall" might be a huge drawback as one can clone the instance and have multiple systems with same id.

Comment: If you've got some custom industrial motherboard, your best chance is to consult its service manual or check with the vendor. It may or may not contain a CPU accessible unique identifier in one form or another (such as unique id eeprom accessible over i2c).